# ART - A Reporting Tool - Default values on queries

Tags: date, reporting, parameter-passing, dashboard

I'm using [ART](http://art.sourceforge.net/) - A Reporting Tool - to build a simple, lightweight, BI prototype.

I have a portal-like structure using a dashboard query. When the user selects it, he is able to select which year and month he wants to visualize. I used a Year parameter and a chained Month parameter - bot use LOV queries, because not all years will have all months due to complexities of the business process I'm analysing.

My issue: The user should, upon logging, see this portal with the parameters set to the current year and month. Then have the option to select a specific year\month combination.

I looked at the parameters `Default Value` property, and have no clue on how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official forums solved it: [There is no default way to do that](https://sourceforge.net/p/art/discussion/352129/thread/4eada2ae/).